# Masonary and JQuery reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, masonry

I am using Masonry from http://masonry.desandro.com on a project where I am trying to create a timeline effect for my users.

I wanted to auto refresh the page every so often (10 seconds for testing purposes) but ran into a problem. On the first load it calls the getStatus() function an the page loads perfectly. But after 10 seconds the data is reloaded and the masory is broken.

I think I tried every combo on when to call and recall the library but nothing seems to work. Any ideas how I can get the masonry to work with reloaded content each time. basically rebuild itself correctly when the new data (which is HTML) is delivered to the page? I know I am doing this all wrong but here is what i have in my script block.

```
<script>
container = document.querySelector('#timeline-list');
        msnry = new Masonry( container, {
            // options
            columnWidth: '.col-sm-6',
            itemSelector: '.col-sm-6'
        });
        function getStatus() {
            $.getJSON('/community/get_status', function(data) {
                $('div#timeline-list').html(data.content);
                    msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                        // options
                        columnWidth: '.col-sm-6',
                        itemSelector: '.col-sm-6'
                    });
            });


            setTimeout("getStatus()",10000);
        }

        jQuery(window).load(function(){
            getStatus();
            if(jQuery(window).width() <= 640 ){
            msnry.destroy();
        }

            // check on resize
            jQuery(window).resize(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).width() <= 640 )
                    msnry.destroy();
            });

        });
    </script>
```

The reload function returns all the col-sm-6 divs and data in HTML.

I've tried .layout and .reloadedItems and neither of them seem to work (or exist for what it's telling me. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific with "broken"? 
Maybe you need to use [ImagesLoaded Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#imagesloaded)

If my memory serves me right its a separate library nowadays [Images Loaded Source](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

Comment: Sorry, broken as in all in 1 column. Will image loaded work when it HTML coming back and not images...probably a dumb question. Would I put it in my getJSON() function($data)?

Comment: I tried your code in an html page with jquery 1.9.1 and masonry 3.3.0 with no problem. One column means you probably have a script error. Please check your browser console and post your error here. 
if there is no error inspect your new cols and check if there is any inline css and post it here. If there is no error or css post your json

Comment: Thank you. I removed an inline when I was generating the HTML and that seems to be the culprit. Thanks for the memory jog